# NameError: name 'RNN_configs_path' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

This is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path

home = str(Path.home())
if home == '/Users/briannaglenn/Documents/Projects/Princeton 2024':
    projects_folder = home
    data_save_path = home + f'/rnn_coach/data/trained_RNNs/{taskname}'
    RNN_configs_path = home + '/rnn_coach/data/configs/{taskname}'

disp = True
config_dict = json.load(
    open(os.path.join(RNN_configs_path, train_config_file), mode="r", encoding='utf-8'))
```

I kept editing the '`RNN_configs_path`' pathway

Why do I keep getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'RNN_configs_path' is not defined
```

Comment: Please output the content of the `home` variable before the `if` statement and place a `print` statement inside the `if` block. When the `if` block is not executed, then `RNN_configs_path` will not be set.

Comment: If `home` is not the value you expect, then `RNN_configs_path` never gets defined; yet you expect it to be defined in `open(os.path.join(RNN_configs_path,...` - why?